# XPathNavigator - MoveTo -> XPath Expression

Tags: .net, xml, xmldocument

Does someone know how to move the cursor of an System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator (created by XML.XmlDocument.CreateNavigator) to a position defined by an XPath-Expression?
My Problem is that i have to use relative paths but the XPathNavigator does not provide any function as far as i know

Cadburry:
thanks,
i'v tried it but the .moveNext() method only returns TRUE only one time and the navigators cursor points still to the root element. (ni.current.InnerXML returns my xml)

my xml simplified:

```
<Ediakt>
<Header>        
</Header>
<MetaData>  
</MetaData>
<Payload>
    <Layer2>    
    </Layer2>           
    <Layer2>    
    </Layer2>
    <Layer2>    
    </Layer2>
</Payload>
</Ediakt>
```

and my xPath expression is ie: /Ediakt/Payload/Layer[2]

Answer (score 0):

You achieve it by selecting the node by passing it as XpathExpression and then Move

```
XPathNodeIterator ni = myNavigator.Select(xPathExpression);
while (ni.MoveNext())
{
///    .....
}
```

Comment: @Cadburry did you try my solution I yes then please can you tell me what is the error

Comment: yes i'v tried it - but if try to replace the node by using 
ni.Current.ReplaceSelf("new xmlstring") an exception is thown: like "the navigators position is invalid"

Comment: why do you want to do  ni.Current.ReplaceSelf("new xmlstring") because thats what is not in your question

Comment: ur right - but it doesnt matter, the position has not changed! - btw: i found a solution with your post (thx) - i have to compile the xPath expression first and set the context to my namespacemanager (i do not use ns in my xml). I will post the full soultion in 4 hours, because i cant do it now (less than 10 reputation ;) )

Comment: @Cadburry im happy its sorted for you :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to HatSoft for the inspiration:

if i compile the expression first and set the context to my namespacemanager - then it works!!

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression ex = System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression.Compile("myexpression");
ex.SetContext(mynamespacemanager);


System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator ni = nav.Select(ex);
// ni.Current.ReplaceSelf()
//ni.m()
while (ni.MoveNext()) {
}
```